# Query count and function not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the code below to select items and using the $result variable to do a count.  if there are less than 1 it will say add more and if there are more than 5 it will say view all.  It works for less than 1 but it won't for more than 5.  Am i doing it right?

//Query

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, why, date_time 
          FROM tabs 
         WHERE p_id = '$pid'
      ORDER BY id 
         LIMIT 0, 5";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

if ($result == "") {
  echo "";
}

echo "";

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0) {
  print("");
} elseif($rows > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $w = nl2br($row['why']);
    $y = $row['date_time'];

    print("echoing contents here");
  }
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 5) {
  echo "view all";
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
  echo "add one";
} ?>
```

Comment: What is being output for a standard example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 5) {
  echo "view all";
  }

 if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
   echo "add one";
  }
```

Should be

```
 if($rows > 5) {
  echo "view all";
  }

 if($rows < 1) {
   echo "add one";
  }
```

Since you exhausted the result set with the previous `mysql_fetch_array()` loop